# webpack 5 configuration with rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpack-5, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm migrating my project to rails 7 and configuring webpack 5. This same project uses bootstrap. I'm having trouble configuring webpack. It only compiles my scss files if they are in the same folder as the js files. But I want to keep them separate for better organization.

The structure of my project is:

```
- app
  - assets
    - stylesheets
      - aplication.scss
      - admin.scss
      - sessions.scss
  - javascript
    - packs
      - aplication.js
      - admin.js
- config
  - webpack
    - webpack.config.js
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
const { webpackConfig, merge } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const path = require('path')

const customConfig = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    application: [ './javascript/packs/application.js', './javascript/packs/stylesheets/application.scss' ],
    admin: [ './javascript/packs/admin.js', './javascript/packs/stylesheets/admin.scss' ],
    sessions: [ './javascript/packs/stylesheets/sessions.scss' ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: '[name][contenthash].js',
    clean: true,
    assetModuleFilename: '[name][ext]'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [ MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ],
      },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
      jquery_ui: 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js'
    }
  }
}

module.exports = merge(webpackConfig, customConfig)
```

The compilation result is:

```
- public
  - packs
    - js
      ...compiled js files
```

Package.json my project:

```
{
  "name": "my_project",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.4.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.7",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.4.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "jquery": "^3.7.0",
    "sass": "^1.62.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3"
  }
}
```

Gemfile with:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 7.0.4'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.x'
```

Webpacker only compiles my scss files if I transfer them into the javascript>packs folder. But I don't want to mix. I would like to continue with my structure or else have javascript>stylesheets. can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing issues on trying to update my Rails (6) project to work with Webpack 5+ version.

Webpacker gem works as a wrapper between Webpack js lib and Rails. As you are using a Wepacker gem version 5, it will only be compatible with Webpack 4.x.x. In order to configure your project to work with Webpack 5+ version I am trying to upgrade my Webpacker gem from v5 to v6 by following: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/v6_upgrade.md .

I am not sure if that will be compatible with webpack 5+. But if not, I am also trying to replace Webpacker gem by Shakapacker gem by following: https://github.com/shakacode/shakapacker/blob/master/docs/v6_upgrade.md#examples-of-v5-to-v6 . Maybe that could give you some inspiration